# How to inverse a key to array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Not sure if I have got the wording correct here, but I have this table:

```
| name  | pets          |
|-------|---------------|
| bob   | cat, dog    |
| steve | cat, parrot |
| dave  | dog         |
```

and I want it to become this:

```
| pet    | names        |
|--------|--------------|
| dog    | bob, dave  |
| cat    | bob, steve |
| parrot | steve      |
```

Comment: There's no reason for potential responders to guess the schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
select   regexp_split_to_table(pets, '\W\s') as pet
        ,string_agg(name, ', ')              as names
from     t
group by regexp_split_to_table(pets, '\W\s')
```

| pet | names |
| --- | --- |
| cat | bob, steve |
| dog | bob, dave |
| parrot | steve |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6fcc1Vmd)

Answer (score 0):

You can `unnest` the array and use a `cross join` to regroup:

```
select v, array_agg(t.name) from tbl t cross join unnest(t.pets) v group by v
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/s2cNFe9i).